Using Python's winreg, how can I make changes to the Windows Registry that I can confirm worked in Regedit?
My python code is below. Online guides and Stack Overflow posts suggest this should work, but it doesn't seem to. When I change the registry, it does a new get to confirm the change was made properly and, according to that result, it shows that the value IS changing. Additionally, if I kill the Flask server and restart it, the page shows the change as well
But I can't confirm the changes in the actual registry. When I check Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager the SubscribedContent-310093Enabled value never changes (yes, I'm pressing f5 to reload... even tried closing and reopening Regedit).
The code thinks it changed something though. If I click the button to toggle the setting, kill the flask server, and re-run, it shows the opposite setting (weirdly I have to reload the actual flask server and can't just reload the webpage).
What am I doing wrong?
import winreg

key_path = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager"
value_name = "SubscribedContent-310093Enabled"
broke_val = 1
fixed_val = 0 

#fix the setting or no? Change between runs to see if the registry changes
fix_it = 0

try:
    # Open the registry key for reading and writing
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path, 0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WRITE)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Handle if the key doesn't exist
    key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path)

# Get the current value of the registry key
try:
    current_value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, value_name)
    current_value = int(current_value)  # Convert value to integer
except FileNotFoundError:
    current_value = None  # No previous value if the value doesn't exist

note = None
try:
    change_to = fixed_val if (fix_it == 1) else broke_val
    if change_to == current_value:
        note = "no change"
    else:
        # Set the new value for the registry key
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, value_name, 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, change_to)
        # Another GET just to be sure the change worked
        current_value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, value_name)
        current_value = int(current_value)  # Convert value to integer
        if current_value != change_to:
            note = "change failed!"
except Exception as e:
    # If the update fails, set the previous and current values to be the same
    print(f"Error setting registry value: {e}")
    note = f"Error setting registry value: {e}"

winreg.CloseKey(key)
print({
    "current": current_value,
    "fixed_val": fixed_val,
    "broke_val": broke_val,
    "is_fixed": (current_value == fixed_val),
    "note": note
})


Is the Flask code relevant to this problem? Please provide a [mre] that only includes relevant functions.

@Barmar, fixed it

@Barmar, I now have a minimal reproducible example posted.

Don't expect me to respond. I don't know anything about Windows registry management.

I added a few other registry tweaks and they seem to be working AFTER I ran VsCode as admin. However, the setting described above doesn't seem to change in the registry even after restart.
